# Input label not at center of select dropdown box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to center my text in the middle of the select dropdown for some reason.
[Implementation status field in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z66iK.png)

Here is my code

```
  <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
        <InputLabel
          htmlFor="Implementation Status"
          style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
          margin="dense"
        >
          Implementation Status
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="Implementation Status"
          name="name"
          onChange={handleChange("Status")}
          defaultValue={values.Status}
          variant="outlined"
          inputProps={{
            id: "Implementation Status",
            name: "age"
          }}
          >
          <MenuItem value="Implemented">Implemented</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Implementation in Progress">
            Implementation in Progress
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Not Implemented">Not Implemented</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
style={{ marginLeft: 20, marginTop: -10 }}
```

in the InputLabel
will make [image: in the center]